# How to split a string into many parts before draw on a view in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi in my application I have to generate PDF file by getting data from an Array.Pdf generation is done successfully using UIKit methods like drawrect and by using

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
```

But here I am facing one issue while draw a description (Getting from array) on pdf. In array few descriptions length will be more than the page size. That time I have to draw part of string in page 1 and remaining in page 2. Here I am not geeting any logic to get exact string length which we can draw in page 1 fully. So can you please let me know the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to check remaining space in page 1 and then compare your remaining height and content height. if content height is more than the remaining page size than you have to continue to next page. You can get your content size by size = [YourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:20.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Comment: Or just draw it and let it be clipped.  The world will still turn if that happens...

Comment: I am done like this in my application and it successfully work for me.

Comment: Hi pradhyuman chavda thanks for your reply. But here my concern is I can continue to newxy page but from where the string have to draw in next page that is my question. How can we find the character from where we have to draw in next page. Please can you please share any code to me. that will be helpful to me.